# I want to draw a rectangle in my core-plot,and it can be scale in/out as the plot space scale in/out.How can I do?

Tags: core-plot

In my iPhone app, a user should draw a custom rectangle anywhere in my core-plot space, and he can scale in/out as the plot space scales in/out. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `CPTBorderedLayer` to display a rectangle with a border and/or fill and attach it to the graph as a plot space annotation. The annotation will move with the plot as it scrolls around. You can use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space and adjust the size of the annotation as necessary.

Comment: OK! Thanks you very much Eric, You are my idol!  I have a try then tell you the result!

Comment: OK, I have resolved it use the CPTPlotSpaceDelegate. So thanks to you! You are my idol!